# Potts model for image analysis

Tags: image-processing

I'm trying to get a hold of the Potts model for image analysis, and this is what is posted on Wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potts_model#The_Potts_model_in_signal_and_image_processing
$$
P_\gamma(u) = \gamma \| \nabla u \|_0 + \| u-f\|_p^p = \gamma \# \{ i : u_i \neq u_{i+1} \} + \sum_{i=1}^n |u_i - f_i|^p
$$
I'm a little bit at a loss however.  Can anybody try to explain the model in their own Words?  and what does the # mean in the equation above?

Comment: $\#A$ denotes the number of elements in the set $A$. So $\#\{i:u_i\ne u_{i+1}\}$ is the number of samples $u_i$ that differ from the next sample $u_{i+1}$.